# Spring MVC form wrong character encoding

Tags: spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a spring MVC application with a feedback form that sends the user's feedback via jquery .get method to `feedbackEmailSend.html` URL.

Here is the controller action that responds to this URL

```
@RequestMapping("/**/feedbackEmailSend.html")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> feedbackEmailSend(@RequestParam(required=false) String name, @RequestParam(required=false) String email, @RequestParam(required=false) String comment, @RequestParam(required=false) String currentPage, HttpServletRequest request){
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(name) & StringUtil.isNotEmpty(comment) & StringUtil.isNotEmpty(email) & StringUtil.isNotEmpty(currentPage)){
        mailSendingService.sendFeedbackByMail(name, email, comment, currentPage, request);
        return Collections.singletonMap("success", "true");
    }else{
        return Collections.singletonMap("failure", "true");
    }
}
```

If the user enters Arabic characters, the `comment` parameter is received corrupted as following `Ø£ÙŠ ÙƒÙ„Ø§Ù… Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠ`

I have checked some other threads and all the solutions was about setting the `encodingFilter` in the web.xml and in my application it is the first filter and all the other forms works fine.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this form ?

Comment: Did you add a `CharacterEncodingFilter` to your web.xml using `UTF-16` as the encoding?

Comment: no, I set it as UTF-8

Comment: did you solve your problem ?